# CSS3 Flexible Box Layout (latest) Maximum Height

Tags: google-chrome, css, webkit, flexbox

I'm using the [latest](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-css3-flexbox-20120918/) flexible box spec (currently only supported by the latest Chrome as far as I know) and am trying to stop the flex items from exceeding a maximum height.

**Best explained with an example: http://jsbin.com/efedof/2/edit**

The first examples `.content` (plus the two `.bar` elements) does not exceed the height of `300px`, so is correct. But with the second example the text pushes the bottom of `.content` down, outside of the `.box` div.

How do I enforce a maximum total height of the three combined flex items, so that the `.content` area becomes scrollable instead of stretching outside of the `.box` and pushing the `.bar` out of the `.box`?

Thanks.

Comment: Will "latest" have the same meaning six months from now? Better to be specific.

Comment: Well it's reached Candidate Recommendation, so I imagine so. But, there are two older specs, and it gets confusing, so fair point: http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-css3-flexbox-20120918/

Answer (score 5):

[Found the answer!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12022288/how-to-keep-a-flex-item-from-overflowing-due-to-its-text). Trick is to add `min-height: 0;` to the `.content` div.

Comment: Suprisingly, Chrome v38.0 displays the boxes OK without `min-height:0`, but FF v33 overflows the content in bottom box. Do you have the same effect?

Comment: Your solution worked for me on Firefox as well. Is it a bug from Firefox ?