# Prevent CSS3 flex-shrink from crushing content

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a flexible layout in CSS3 with 3 boxes stacked on each other. The boxes are siblings and thus have the same parent element. The height of the first box must fit its content. The height of the following two boxes shall **grow** to fit their respective content until they're about to overflow their parent. In that case, they shall shrink so that they don't overflow.

The problem is that I can't figure out how to prevent one of the shrinking boxes from becoming crushed if its content is small in relation to the other shrinking box. I want those boxes to shrink down to a certain point where they won't shrink anymore – let's say the equivalent of two rows of text for example. Setting `min-width` isn't an option because I don't want the boxes to be taller than their content in case the content is only one row for example. If any of the boxes has come to the point where it shall not shrink anymore and the parent can't hold them without overflowing, the parent shall get a scrollbar.

I don't know the content in advance so the layout has to be dynamic. I want to solve this only with CSS, if possible.

Here's an example of the problem where *box3* is too small:

```css
p {
    margin: 0;
}
.container, .box {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.box {
    background-color: white;
    margin: 1em;
    overflow: auto;
}
#container {
    background-color: yellow;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 15em;
    overflow: auto;
}
#box1 {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}
#box2 {
}
#box3 {
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="container">
    <div id="box1" class="box">
        <p>◼</p>
    </div>
    <div id="box2" class="box">
        <p>◼◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻</p>
        <p>◼◼◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻</p>
        <p>◼◼◼◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻</p>
        <p>◼◼◼◼◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻</p>
        <p>◼◼◼◼◼◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻</p>
        <p>◼◼◼◼◼◼◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻</p>
        <p>◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻</p>
        <p>◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻</p>
        <p>◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻</p>
        <p>◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◻◻◻◻◻◻◻◻</p>
        <p>◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◻◻◻◻◻◻◻</p>
        <p>◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◻◻◻◻◻◻</p>
        <p>◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◻◻◻◻◻</p>
        <p>◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◻◻◻◻</p>
        <p>◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◻◻◻</p>
        <p>◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◻◻</p>
        <p>◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◻</p>
        <p>◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼◼</p>
    </div>
    <div id="box3" class="box">
        <p>◼◻◻</p>
        <p>◼◼◻</p>
        <p>◼◼◼</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 41):

IF I understand your question correctly, the flex-shrink property should be what you are looking for.

Set #box1 to `flex-shrink: 0`

Set #box2 to `flex-shrink: 1`

Set #box3 to `flex-shrink: 1`

Comment: I don't have access to a browser that supports flex-boxes at the moment, but I think _box2_ and _box3_ have `flex-shrink` set to `1` by default. That means that they'll shrink until their heights are `0`, which is the problem.

Comment: Test it first before you speculate. Flexbox is quite tricky at first.

Comment: I can now confirm that `flex-shrink` is `1` by default (at least in Chrome and Firefox), so your solution doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks, but isn't that exactly what you proposed in your answer? As I wrote, it doesn't work :( _box3_ is still getting squashed.

Comment: Just change the flex-shrink for each of the boxes. If you want box3 to maintain two lines, set box2 to flex-shrink: 2;.

Comment: It may work in the example, but it's just an example. It won't work in the general case since I don't know the content of the boxes in advance. To clarify; I need a limit to the shrinking so that the boxes don't get too narrow.

Comment: That's exactly what flex-shrink does, it limits the amount a flex item can be shrunk. Check out this pen with some fake text. Also, just for future questions and maintaining good will, make sure to use an relevant example. You don't want SO users to solve a sample that doesn't actually work for what you need it for.

Comment: No, flex-shrink doesn't limit the amount a flex item can be shrunk. It's a factor that determines how much the element it applies to shall shrink in relation to its siblings. The example I provided with the question was just to illustrate the general case I'm trying to solve. I can't provide an example for every case naturally.

Comment: Chromium 38 and it works for me -- `flex-grow` was crushing the other (fixed) element and setting `flex-shrink` to `0` worked as a guard against crushing. Thank you for the tip!