# How to prevent the input field from pushing the last element beyond the div?

Tags: html, forms, css, flexbox

This codepen http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/JKPeoY demonstrates my problem. When I decrease browser width then the icon on the right gets pushed out to the right by the input field. Is there a way to prevent this?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="search-group">
  <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
  <input type="text" class="search-field">
  <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-random"></i></span>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.search-group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #777;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.icon {
  background: #ccc;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0.8em 1em;
}

.search-field {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  flex: 1;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 0.8em 1em;
}
```

**SOLUTION:**

As advised below, adding `width: 100%` or `width: inherit` to the `.search-field` has solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you are facing problem in the width of textbox. textbox is not changing his size according to the screen size.

```
.search-field {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  flex: 1;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 0.8em 1em;
  width:100%;
}
```

I add `width:100%;` and its seems good. Please check this out.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from here: [How to keep a flex item from overflowing due to its text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12022288/how-to-keep-a-flex-item-from-overflowing-due-to-its-text)

**W3C specification says, "By default, flex items won't shrink below their minimum content size (the length of the longest word or fixed-size element). To change this, set the ‘min-width’ or ‘min-height’ property."**

So you just need to add "min-width: 1px;" to the search-field and it will work

Comment: THIS solved my problems with the input not behaving correctly. Much love <3

Answer (score 1):

set width as,

```
.search-field {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  flex: 1;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 0.8em 1em;
  width:inherit;    /* will take parent container width*/
```

}