# Flex item filled with text overflowing flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am facing almost the same problem as in this question:

- [How to keep a flex item from overflowing due to its text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12022288/how-to-keep-a-flex-item-from-overflowing-due-to-its-text)

And this solution works perfectly:

```css
.container {
    display: -webkit-flex; 
}

.container>div:first-child{
    white-space:nowrap;
   -webkit-order:1;
   -webkit-flex: 1;
   -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto; /*important*/
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow:hidden;
    min-width:0px; /* new algorithm mises the calculation of the width */
}

.container > div:last-child {
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -webkit-order:2;
    background: red;
    -webkit-flex:1 0 auto; /*important*/
}
.container > div:first-child:hover{
    white-space:normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div>foo barfoo bar</div>
    <div>foo bar</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
        <div>foo barfoo barfoo barfoo barfoo barfoo barfoo bar
        foo barfoo barfoo barfoo barfoo barfoo barfoo bar
        foo barfoo barfoo barfoo barfoo barfoo barfoo bar</div>
    <div>foo bar</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div>foo barfoo bar</div>
    <div>foo bar</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
        <div>foo barfoo barfoo barfoo barfoo barfoo barfoo bar
        foo barfoo barfoo barfoo barfoo barfoo barfoo bar
        foo barfoo barfoo barfoo barfoo barfoo barfoo bar</div>
    <div>foo bar</div>
</div><div class="container">
    <div>foo barfoo bar</div>
    <div>foo bar</div>
</div>
```

([jsFiddle version](http://jsfiddle.net/iamanubhavsaini/zWtBu/))

But if I put the presented div in a div with `display: flex`, my problem comes back.

Here is the full code which does not work. The problem is exactly the same as in the above question.

```css
.container {
    display: flex; 
}

.container>div:first-child{
    white-space:nowrap;
   -webkit-order:1;
   -webkit-flex: 1;
   -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto; /*important*/
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow:hidden;
    min-width:0px; /* new algorithm mises the calculation of the width */
}

.container > div:last-child {
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -webkit-order:2;
    background: red;
    -webkit-flex:1 0 auto; /*important*/
}


.test-flex {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="test-flex">
  <div class="container">
          <div>foo barfoo barfoo barfoo barfoo barfoo barfoo bar
          foo barfoo barfoo barfoo barfoo barfoo barfoo bar
          foo barfoo barfoo barfoo barfoo barfoo barfoo bar</div>
      <div>foo bar</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> ... if I put the presented div in a div with `display: flex`, my problem comes back. ... The problem is exactly the same as in the above question.

The solution is also the same as in [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12022288/3597276): *Add `min-width: 0` to the flex item.*

As described in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12131365/3597276) to that question, a flex item by default cannot be smaller than the size of its content.

Now that you've created a new primary container (`.test-flex`), you've made the previous primary container (`.container`) a flex item.

You now need to override the default setting on flex items (`min-width: auto`) to allow `.container` to shrink past the size of its children (the divs with the text).

You can do that with:

- `min-width: 0`, or
- `overflow: hidden`

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  min-width: 0;  /* NEW */
}
.container>div:first-child {
  white-space: nowrap;
  order: 1;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 0px;
}
.container > div:last-child {
  order: 2;
  background: red;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
.test-flex {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="test-flex">
  <div class="container">
    <div>foo barfoo barfoo barfoo barfoo barfoo barfoo bar foo barfoo barfoo barfoo barfoo barfoo barfoo bar foo barfoo barfoo barfoo barfoo barfoo barfoo bar</div>
    <div>foo bar</div>
  </div>
</div>
```